# Combine multiple csv files by column without pandas

Tags: python, csv, file

I need to join 4 csv files into one without using pandas based on specific column. I managed to do it with 2 files. But struggle with adding more files to the joined one.
the files have columns:

```
  stoptimes.txt 
  trip_id,departure_time,stop_id 
  stops.txt 
  stop_id,stop_code,stop_name  
  trips.txt
  route_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,vehicle_id  
  vehicles.txt
  vehicle_type_id,vehicle_type_name
```

desired output is to have all of them in one file
I wanted to join stoptimes and stops on stop_id column, then join to this file trip.txt on trip_id column, and then join vehicles file  on vehicle_type_id column

```py
stoptimes = []
with open('stop_times.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        stoptimes.append(line.split(','))

stops = []
with open('stops.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        stops.append(line.split(','))

trips = []
with open('trips.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        trips.append(line.split(','))

vehicletypes = []
with open('vehicle_types.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    vehicletypes.append(line.split(','))

for (trip_id, arrival_time, departure_time, stop_id, stop_sequence, pickup_type, drop_off_type) in stoptimes:
    for (stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon) in stops:
        if stop_id == stop_id:
            print(stop_id, stop_name, trip_id, departure_time)
```

Comment: Could you precise what's the content of your csv files, and what's the expected output ? What do you *exactly* mean by 'combine 4 csv files' ? Concatenate them ? We cannot help you if you don't precisely define what you want to achieve.

Comment: It looks like you're performing a 'join' from `stoptimes` to `stops` - are you looking to expand that join to the other two tables? What are the columns you're looking to join on? You should probably provide some example data that shows some relevant lines of data in the 4 files.

Comment: I've just added some more details

Comment: it'll be easier in pandas. why do you not want to use pandas?